# monitor won't return to display main screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have a Pc (windows 8.1) and a laptop.

My monitor is connected to both of them. 
I have set the monitor to show the laptop only instead of the PC (main).

I worked for a while and then I have unplugged the laptop from the monitor.

usually the monitor would have displayed the PC, but now it doesn't. Shows black screen.

I did restart, but it didn't help.

The monitor shows windows starting and then turns black.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you tell the monitor which machine to use and how do you connect to both machines? Or are you just switching the cable between each machine?

Comment: If the monitor shows windows starting then the problem most likely lies in your PC (screen resolution/refresh settings). Try booting into safe mode and see if you get an image

Answer (score 0):

If "both" means your monitor is connected to PC and laptop simultaneously, I think your monitor has at least two ports (a typical scenario is connecting the monitor to PC via DVI and to laptop via VGA).

In this case, the monitor usually has a button on the panel (or an option in its menu) to choose which input signal to display. Try to switch the monitor to the correct channel.

Alternatively, you can also try the "auto adjust" button (there usually is) to let the monitor auto detect signal. If you are sure the right channel is selected but there's still nothing, try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on your PC to adjust the external display setting.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor usually keeps the previous setup of your connection. You need to connect the laptop again in order for you to reconfigure the monitor and set your screen to your PC.